# Build docker image of elasticsearch with sample data

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, dockerfile

I want to use an official image of elasticsearch, and build this image with some sample data (JSON files) that I have on my local machine.
So, the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM library/elasticsearch:2
```

Then I run `sudo docker build -t test/elasticsearch .` from the folder where my Dockerfile is located in order to build the image.

Finally I start the elasticsearch server as follows:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -v /home/gosper/tests/ets/tempdata/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data test/elasticsearch
```

As it can be noticed I miss the step when the existing data (a JSON file) is passed to the docker image. How can I do it? Should I add some lines to Dockerfile. Or should I create my own image...?

Comment: I think you should add some lines to Dockerfile

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon: Ok, but which ones?:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an elasticsearch image which has some data, just by extending the ES official image and copying your data folder into /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

```
FROM elasticsearch
MAINTAINER mlabouardy 

COPY /your/data/folder /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Comment: When I run `sudo docker build -t test/elasticsearch .`, it now says `usr/share/elasticsearch/data/test.json: not a directory`

Comment: try this:
COPY /your/data/folder/ /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
RUN ls -la /files/*

Comment: Now it says `INFO[0000] usr/share/elasticsearch/data/: no such file or directory`, however this directory exists. The problem is that instead of `/usr/...` it takes `usr/...`, while in my Dockerfile I have a copy-paste of your code.